# How to cause collision in Python Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am new to Python 3 and I am currently making a turtle game where if you hit a red turtle, you go to the start. I do not know how to make the player move to make them collide.  My code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

wn = Screen()
wn.bgcolor("black")

artist = Turtle()
artist.color('white')
artist.speed(0)
artist.penup()
artist.setposition(-300, -300)
artist.pendown()
artist.pensize(4)
for side in range(4):
    artist.fd(600)
    artist.lt(90)
artist.hideturtle()

player = Turtle()
player.color("white")
player.penup()
player.setposition(260, 260)
player.speed(10)

enemy = Turtle('circle')
enemy.color('red')
enemy.penup()
enemy.speed(9)

if player.distance(enemy) < 5:
    player.hideturtle()
    player.setposition(260, 260)
    player.showturtle()
```

Comment: please edit your question with correct tab indentation

Answer (score 0):

> I do not know how to make them collide and move the player, it won't
>   move.

Since the OP used a proper turtle import (for turtle's Object-Oriented API) and used the `distance()` method instead of reimplementing one like many folks, +1!

Below I've reworked the code to provide player movement, so that it can finally collide with the enemy.  To keep this example minimalist, I've made the boundary circular instead of rectangular as in the original:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RADIUS = 300
CURSOR_RADIUS = 10
CURSOR_DIAMETER = CURSOR_RADIUS * 2
START = RADIUS / 2 ** 0.5 - CURSOR_DIAMETER

def move_forward():
    screen.onkey(None, 'Up')  # disable handler inside handler

    player.forward(CURSOR_RADIUS)
    if player.distance(0, 0) >= RADIUS:
        player.undo()

    if player.distance(enemy) < CURSOR_RADIUS:
        player.hideturtle()
        player.setposition(START, START)
        player.showturtle()

    screen.onkey(move_forward, 'Up')  # reenable handler

screen = Screen()
screen.bgcolor('black')

artist = Turtle(visible=False)
artist.color('white')
artist.speed('fastest')
artist.pensize(4)

artist.penup()
artist.sety(-RADIUS)
artist.pendown()

artist.circle(RADIUS)

artist.penup()
artist.setposition(START, START)
artist.pendown()

artist.dot(CURSOR_DIAMETER, 'green')

enemy = Turtle('circle')
enemy.color('red')
enemy.penup()

player = Turtle()
player.speed('fastest')
player.color('white')

player.penup()
player.setposition(START, START)
player.setheading(player.towards(enemy))

screen.onkey(lambda: player.right(45), 'Right')
screen.onkey(lambda: player.left(45), 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_forward, 'Up')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

You can control the player with the arrow keys.  Now the enemy needs to be made to do something other than just sit in the middle.